# React-native-flipper configuration failed

Tags: android, react-native

I have some problem with react-native-flipper. When I try to run project I take:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-flipper'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\Roman\Documents\Projects\sun-travel-mob-app\node_modules\react-native-flipper\android\build.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\Roman\.gradle\caches\jars-8\ea8ce0fa9df2da4febe4fc342eeab851\cp_proj.jar\build_48r7k7zidgtcv2a8jpll1k8l5.class does not exist.
```

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem like this, just delete gradle cache at C:/Users/User/.gradle/caches